# Как правильно выстроить отношения и спроектировать таблицы?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Всем привет! Нужен совет.

**Есть таблица пользователей:**

```
Users
-id
-first_name
-last_name
```

**Tаблица компаний:**

```
Company
-id
-name
-slug
-logo
```

**Есть таблица ролей:**

```
Role
-id
-name
```

**Таблица комментариев:**

```
Comment
-id
-company_id (id компании на которую отзыв)
-user_id (id пользователя кто оставил коммент)
-text
```

Суть такова - компания может иметь несколько сотрудников, которые могут управлять теми или иными функциями в профиле: **admin**, **manager**.

Как добавить связь между компанией и сотрудников, чтобы например логиниться в профиль компании могли только сотрудники и когда оставляют ответы на комментарии своей компании вместо своего имя писалось название компании к которой они привязаны?

Comment: Связь простая `company_has_users` ("user_id", "company_id"). Остальное всё уже кодом определяется, база тут не при чем.

Comment: можно и роль добавить? company_has_users ("user_id", "company_id", "role_id") или так уже не правильно?

Comment: Смотря что Вы хотите сделать. Если определять роль (одну, не несколько) для пользователя в конкретной компании, то можно так.